# How to Run Large SQL File in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a huge (~500mb) SQL file that I need to run on my database. It is a data dump from a production database that I need to put into my development database. Normally, if it were smaller, I'd paste it into the SQL tab and run it, but that would definitely blow up my browser.

If I import that SQL file into the development database, is is just like running the SQL file? Or is the import function specifically set to *import a whole* database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try to import it from the console, so you do not depend on the file upload limitations:

```
C:>  mysql -u root -p < file.sql
```

Comment: I don't have sudo permissions via SSH unfortunately and this means that I cannot run mysql commands. I have to do this via phpMyAdmin

Comment: in this case you depend on the PHP settings, for max file upload. Any way you can change that? Also, is the file zipped?

Comment: there are also some tools that split the file in more parts, without breaking the queries, like: http://rodo.nl/index.php?page=mysql-splitter

Comment: @nucleogenesis, you don't need sudo privileges. The MySQL 'root' user is not the same as the Linux 'root' user.

Comment: @Bill Karwin I think you made me feel stupid, in a good way. :) Thanks! I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @cornelb I can get the SQL file uploaded when zipped. The primary concern I have is-- does Import essentially just RUN the file? Or are there backside settings that make Import specific for importing entire databases? I'm just importing 10 tables or so.

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean, but the sql file should contain `use database_name`. The queries will done in that database. that's it.

Comment: The dump file will not necessarily contain `use database_name`. Depends on which options were used when the dump file was created. It would be safest to specify the database to import into: `mysql -u root -p  database_name < file.sql`

Comment: @Bill Karwin - I don't have the root user password for the database. I'm not sure where to get it, but I'm on a shared host and don't know if they'd give me that information.

Comment: @cornelb In phpMyAdmin, if I go to my selected database, hit the Import tab, and Import an SQL file, it will just run my SQL from that file right? Naturally, to that database, since the Import is within that database's Import tab. I was just worried that Import was specifically set to try and create a database or tables or something and figured it prudent to get clarification before risking screwing something up.

Comment: it will run that sql file. You can check if you have `drop` statements before running. Should it only be a data import file?

Comment: Then use the user & password you used to log into phpMyAdmin. You might have enough privileges to run the commands in the SQL file.

Comment: @cornelb Thanks, I appreciate the help. It is specifically a Data (no structure) dump from a Magento database. I will truncate old data and put new data in its place so get the dev site up to date before going live.

Comment: @Bill Karwin - Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I tried my username and password and it didn't let me in. I asked for raised permissions recently (I couldn't even create a database!) but it doesn't seem to have been done.

Comment: Okay, you'll have to follow up with your hosting provider. That user & password may be restricted to work only when connecting from the host where phpmyadmin runs.

Comment: @Bill Karwin - From your previous answer, I first used my login/pass for logging into phpMyAdmin. While that didn't work, it inspired me to try the actual database login/password. That worked! I'm very new to Unix command line and I'm now going to be able to take care of this work very quickly from your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest two options that you can try:

1.I would say try BigDump. I had the exact same problem before. You can read and follow this article for more information:

http://moeamine.com/how-to-upload-a-big-sql-file-to-mysql

You can download big dump from the link below:

http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/

2.you can gzip or bzip the file and phpMyAdmin will decompress and run the script. Another option is to split the MYSQL file into number of files and load each of them individually.

Comment: The issue isn't the size. My question is does Import just RUN the sql file, or does it have other settings that make it specific to importing whole databases.

Comment: @nucleogenesis The Import command will run the SQL statements that are in the file you give it.  This could be simple selects, alter tables, create databases, or full restores, depending on what is in the file you upload.

Comment: @nucleogenesis: I would have said the exact same thing what Steven Scott has said

Answer (score 0):

I have restored DB by a sql file of size almost like 2.2GB, and I think MySQL GUI Tools are the best for that purpose. They give you a handy approach of the most operations.

Download from [Download My Sql GUI Tools](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/gui/)

They are like 7-8 years old but worked like a charm for me.